# Displaying different characters instead of special characters

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I am new to sl4a. My problem is that when I type following characters (special characters except `@`) from keyboard in python interpreter in android emulator, it displays the unexpected characters.

When I type `shift+1(!)` it displays `^[0P` and following:

```
shift+3(#) => ^[0R
shift+4($) => ^[0S
shift+5(%) => ^[[15~
shift+6(^) => ^[[17~
shift+7(&) => ^[[18~
shift+8(*) => ^[[19~
shift+9[(] => ^[[20~
shift+0()) => ^[[21~
```

Why the interpreter is displaying the unexpected characters (as mentioned above)?
Please help me to get rid of the problem.

Comment: I have a similar issue involving the attached keyboard on my Asus eee transformer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the latest [unofficial release](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/Unofficial) had some fixes related to this... Otherwise you could also try running Python in a different terminal, as per [this script](http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/source/browse/python-build/standalone_python.sh).